# How can I write information from file2 to the begin of file1?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

So what I'm trying to do is to copy information from file2 to the begin of file1. If someone could help me I would really appreciate your time, thank you.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

FileInputStream fileReader = new FileInputStream(reader.readLine()); //file1
FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(reader.readLine(), true);  //file2

while (fileReader.available() > 0) {
      int data = fileReader.read();
      fileWriter.write(data);

}

fileReader.close();
fileWriter.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: It's really a bad idea to rewrite the file. You can read file2, write it to file3, read file1 and write it to file3.

Comment: its some sort of exercise i can have only 2 files which readed from console fileReader/fileWriter, but yeah, i cant find any iformation about it in google or book.

Comment: (1) What is the exact problem you are experiencing? (2) Why do you have only one reader for two files? (3) Why are you reading from `System.in` but state that you have **2 files**? where are they?

Comment: you need read and compare beginning file content, then finally write it. further search about read/write/copy files in java on net, you will find more stuff

Comment: Ok,if it's an exercise, you can do this: 1-add a very rare symbol at the end of file2 (like : 1111@@@@2222,.,.,.,.,***) 2- append the file1 to the file2 (after the rare symbol) 3- read (new) file2 from the rare symbol to the end and rewrite on file1 4- read the file2 from the beginning to the rare symbol and write to the file1

Comment: first file is where i get information from is c:/a.txt then i write it to c:/b.txt, im using system.in to bassicaly say to program where the files are

Comment: mok, nah, thats not what i mean.

Comment: "*im using system.in to bassicaly say to program where the files are*" - Ok, understood. You are doing it wrong™. What you do is reading bytes from the STDIN stream. Instead, what you want is to [read the cmd line args](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i Merge files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174843/how-can-i-merge-files)